# SQLite timestamp values in different types

Tags: java, sqlite

I am storing a Timestamp value in a `sqlite` database, but when I access the value in string format it  gives me the right time, but when I try and access it in long, time and Timestamp format  it gives me the wrong time.
 **How can i get it right in Regular-time period format ?**

```
 Creating Table
              String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS graphTable " +

                        "(TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp) " ; 

   /* Access the value from database using java code */

     ResultStatement rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT TIME FROM graphTable ;" );

          while ( rs.next() ) {

                Date resultdate = new Date(rs.getLong()*1000);
                Millisecond ms_read = new Millisecond(resultdate);
               System.out.println( "TIME = " + ms_read );

               }
```

Comment: Then always read it as String. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yeah, there is no prob getting it in string , but i'm unable to convert it in RegularTime peeriod..

Comment: I have to use this time in Dynamic Timeseries chart in java swing . That's why i have to convert it in RegularTime period .

Comment: My suggestion is you store the time as a `long` and to show convert to any relevant Date object/format.

Comment: @m0skit0 After doing all the conversion in Date , Time and other format again it gives same value like 16:33:34 for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are fetching time stamp value from the database, Store that value by using this package

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

instead of `import java.util.Date;`

**Edit**

First define the format like below and then try to convert it.

```
SimpleDateFormat DFTS = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formatteddate=DFTS.format(d);
```

`d` is the date from database

Comment: After using this i get same time (16:00:02) for every row.

Comment: Instead of getting as long, can you try using `rs.getDate()`

Comment: I am getting error while trying to multiply by 1000 in rs.getDate().

Comment: If you want to get the same value from the database, then don't multiply with anything.

Comment: I have to use this time in Dynamic Timeseries chart in java swing . That's why i have to convert it in RegularTime period.

Comment: According to you, i did but it gives me the same (Wed Dec 31 16:00:02 PST 1969) value for every row.

Comment: Again i am getting same thing 12/31/1969 16:00:02 for each row.

Comment: What is the format you need to convert ? What is Regular time period ? Give your expected output.It will help to give solution

Comment: i am storing the time in Timestamp format in database, and i need to extract the time only from DB , so i can put the time into Timeseries charts.

Answer (score 2):

If you want unixtime out of it, use `strftime('%s', ...)`:

```
SELECT strftime('%s', time) FROM graphTable;

// now access the column as long
```

If you want to convert to Java milliseconds value, just multiply by 1000.

Further reading: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: I tried but again not getting right time as in the database.

Comment: If it's java milliseconds you're after, you need to multiply by 1000. Consider adding some detail to the question so people have some idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Actually to get real milliseconds time from SQLite it's `(strftime('%s', 'now') || substr(strftime('%f', 'now') , 3)) * 1000`

Comment: @m0skit0 For current time maybe, for converting existing timestamps - no.

Comment: Look i have to use this time in Dynamic Timeseries chart in java swing .That's why i have to convert it in RegularTime period. And i have to plot the graph according to the time.